# How-to use jenkins environment variable in SVN URL

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

I have a job with SVN branch as parameter ("List subversion tags and more") and try to use jenkins environment variable into SVN URL like : http://my.svn.repos/$JOB_NAME

My goal is to reuse this job for all projects with the same url.

I've tried to use : ${JOB_NAME}, $JOB_NAME, ${env['JOB_NAME']} and ${JOB_NAME##*/} but this never works.

Is it possible ? Thanks !

EDIT : SVN plugin version : 1.54 (2013... It's old but I can't update)

Comment: I tested using `${JOB_NAME}` on one of our git repos (I don't have SVN available to test against) and that works fine for me. What output do you get when you run the job?

Comment: I think that is a bug with svn plugin for jenkins. I don't have problem on checkout but with the build parameter, which list project branches, tags, etc. And this one is the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that the checkout is OK with URL : http://svn.repos/${JOB_NAME}/${BRANCH}. (But this not works with the "build param url"...)